# Qt Creator Application Output pane Stop button: "The program has unexpectedly finished." when running a simple QML app

Tags: user-interface, qt-creator

In Qt Creator, run a dummy QML app as simple as the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
}
```

Go to Application Output pane. Press the Stop button (a tiny red square). An error message will appear. Following is the log:

```
Starting <path>/qtbase/bin/qmlscene...
**The program has unexpectedly finished.**
<path>/qtbase/bin/qmlscene crashed
```

This is a bit confusing or misleading, as no crash has been observed. By contrast, this does not happen when the qmlscene window is closed by clicking the Close (X) button, nor does it happen when running qmlscene using the command line on a terminal.

I'm using Qt 5.5.0 on Linux Ubuntu. But this appears to happen also with other versions of Qt.

Was this designed that way, or could this be improved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have dived into Qt Creator source code. When `Stop` button is clicked, function `ApplicationLauncher::stop()` is called. This function tries to kill or terminate process `qmlscene`, leading to the above-mentioned messages.

So actually `Stop` means "Kill" or "Terminate" the process.

It would help if the label could be renamed accordingly.